# NullPointerException in OnEnable() (Bukkit plugin)

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

My error log is saying on line 13 (In my MainClass) there is an NPE.

My MainClass:

```
package me.p250;

import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.p250.command.BuyCommand;

public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin {

public FileConfiguration config;

public void onEnable() {
    getCommand("a").setExecutor(new BuyCommand(this));
}

public void onDisable() {

    }

}
```

And my other other class:
http://pastebin.com/bYpCnPN2

Comment: probably getCommand returns null:
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#getCommand(java.lang.String)

Comment: why do people still ask NPE questions? is it **that hard** to test?

Comment: yeah.. looking back at this, I've no clue what I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already said, you get a NPE because the command "a" doesn't exist. If you haven't done that already, add it to your .yml file also.

```
commands:
   a:
     description: does something
     usage: /a
```

Edit: Apparently you haven't added it to your onCommand either. Check for the command using

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    //do stuff when /a is executed
}
```

The check for `args` can be done there. Example:

```
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
    if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("test1")){
        //execute code for /a test1
    } else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("test2")){
        //execute code for /a test2
    }
}
```

Comment: All I had to do was register my command in my plugin.yml Since I used CommandExecutor, I didn't have to do is(label.equalsIgnoreCase("a")

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry for my edit, I just realized I was writing nonsense!

Comment: Don't worry, I was also being nonsensical because I should've checked if my command was registered first!! EDIT: Ok what the hell is happening, I'll  post the error log :O

Comment: That's my bad again, should've kept the edit. You still need to check for the actual command within the onCommand method, as written down in my answer.

Comment: That isn't going to help, now your just speaking rubbish :P

Comment: Well, if you want to prevent your code from working you can believe that. But if you take a look at your onCommand you'll see that you are only checking for the args, and not the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

getCommand return null if the command does not exist. Make sure that the "a" command is created.

Comment: I forgot how to make the command "a". How would I put that into my other class?? (I haven't done bukkit in a while!)